# Gallery without selecting a photo exit the app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using ImagePicker package to get image from gallery and it works great

```
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

But when the user press on back button when he is already on gallery without selecting a photo, it kicks the user out of the whole app. So, I want to customize this process as when the user press on the back button, he returns to a specific screen. I tried WillPopScope but it's not working.

Comment: Do any errors appear on your console when no selection is made?

Comment: Nope ..........

Comment: which device (model) You are using to select/capture image? sometimes device caused the problem, on github similar issue is open with image picker.